# No se actualiza la formula calculada por apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, groovy

**Buen día a todos.**

Mi problema reside al generar/leer el valor de una celda ya que esta si se muestra como si estuviera calculada **COLUMNA A** sin embargo al leerla posteriormente, me devuelve solo la formula como se muestra en la **BARRA DE FORMULAS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para introducir la formula hago lo siguiente

```
List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
rows.add("=\"R--\"&B"+ pos+"&\"-- \"&C")
rows.add(colB)//20295
rows.add(colC)//270721
...
try {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0)

    int rowPos = sheet.getLastRowNum();

    for (String rowData: rows) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowPos);

        int columnPos = 0;
        for (String cellData : data) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(columnPos++);
            if(cellData.startsWith("=")){
                cell.setCellFormula(cellData.replace("=", ""));//para la columna A
            }else{
                cell.setCellValue(cellData);
            }
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    workbook.close();
    outputStream.close();

}
```

Existe alguna forma de que se actualice dicha formula. ya que cuando entro a excel y doy un enter a ese campo y despues leeo el valor este si me devuelve el texto esperado

Answer (score 0):

Estuve investigando en la documentación de apache poi y encontre el [evaluador de formulas](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html)
lo que tuve que hacer fue anexar a mi codigo lo siguiente

```
FormulaEvaluator formula = woorkbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator()
...
formula.evaluateAll()
```

por lo que al final lo deje como un metodo generico y quedo de la siguiente manera

```
static void update(File file, String sheetName, List<String> rows) {
        Workbook workbook
        Sheet sheet
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        /*crea la instancia correspondiente de HSSFWorkbook o XSSFWorkbook */
        workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        FormulaEvaluator formula = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        
        sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

        int rowPos = sheet.getLastRowNum();

        for (String rowData: rows) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowPos);

            int columnPos = 0;
            for (String cellData : rowData.split(Pattern.quote("|"))) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(columnPos++);
                /*Podria usarse un Map<Cell.CELL_TYPE,DTO>*/
                if(cellData.startsWith("=")){
                    cell.setCellFormula(cellData.replace("=", ""));
                }else{
                    cell.setCellValue(cellData);
                }
            }
            formula.evaluateAll()
        }

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new MyException("", ex)
    }
}
```